# How to add click event on rectangle in Graphiti.js

Tags: javascript, graphiti-js

I want to register click event on rectangle in graphiti. i tried this

```
var innerrect = new graphiti.shape.basic.Rectangle(100, 20);
        innerrect.onClick = function(){
            alert("Hi");
        }
rect.addFigure(innerrect , new graphiti.layout.locator.BottomLocator(rect));
canvas.addFigure(rect, 100, 100);
```

but wont work. plz let me know abut it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create your own shape inherited from Rectangle like this.
This looks at the first moment a little bit unconfortable, but normaly you write 
your own shapes with a lot of custom code. In this case it is a one time effort to crate a new class.

Keep in mind that the examples are a good starting point. There is a an examples with a click event listener as well.

```
MyFigure = graphiti.shape.basic.Rectangle.extend({

NAME : "MyFigure",

init : function()
{
    this._super();

    this.createPort("output");
    this.setDimension(30,30);
    this.setResizeable(false);

    this.value=false;

    this.colors={};
    this.colors[true]="#00f000";
    this.colors[false]="#f00000";

    this.setBackgroundColor(this.colors[this.value]);
},

/**
 * @method
 * Change the color and the internal value of the figure.
 * Post the new value to related input ports.
 * 
 */
onClick: function(){
    this.value = !this.value;
    this.setBackgroundColor(this.colors[this.value]);

    var connections = this.getOutputPort(0).getConnections();
    connections.each($.proxy(function(i, conn){
        var targetPort = conn.getTarget();
        targetPort.setValue(this.value);
        conn.setColor(this.getBackgroundColor());
    },this));
}

});
```